# How to access to an element in a PHP multidimensional array with a string?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have something like this:

```
function print_element($array, $field){
  return "Element: {$array[$field]}";
}

$array['name_en'] = 'English name';
echo print_element($array, 'name_en');
```

I wish to access a property within an array that belongs to the main array like this:

```
$array['english_values']['name_en'] = 'English name';
echo print_element($array, "['english_values']['name_en']");
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thx in advance.

Comment: If your function doesn't return anything, you don't need to call `echo` before it. Your function handles the `echo` internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo print_element($array['english_values'], 'name_en');
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass just the string 'english_values,name_en' to your function. Inside the function, explode the string on the comma, then loop through the array and assign `$array = $array[$thisKey]` on each pass. You may also wish to check that it `is_array($array)` on each pass.

Answer (score 0):

You have the array and also the keys try this:

```
    function print_var($val) {
        echo "VAR: {$val} <br/>";
    }

    $array['english_values']['name_en'] = 'English name';
    print_var($array['english_values']['name_en']);

    // OUTPUT
    // VAR: English name
```